# How to most easily make never ending incremental offline backups

Tags: linux, backup

I have for some time being thinking I can save some money on external hard drives by making this backup scheme: If I have 3TB data to backup, where less than 1TB changes from one backup to the next and I always want to have 1 copy out of the house, it should be enough to have 3 2TB external hard drives. The idea is that each time a disk is used for backup it is completely filled - a full backup is however never made as 3TB>>2TB.

So the backup starts by taking disk1 filling it with 2TB of data. Then take disk2 filling it with 1TB of data and 1TB of redundant data as it also exist on disk1. Now disk1 and disk2 can be taken out of the house.

When the next backup is made disk2 will already contain 2TB of data, where at least 2TB-1TB=1TB is still valid as only 1TB have changes. So by backing up 2TB of data (where some may also exist on disk2) to disk3 we have a complete backup on disk2+disk3. Now disk3 can be moved out of the house and disk1 can be moved back in, deleted and reused for backup.

This can of course be made better so we can use different sizes of disks, have different number of disks, have higher requirement for number of copies out of the house etc.

In theory it is quite easy to make by having stored checksums of which files is on all disks, so we can check for changes by checking the checksums.

However in practice there is a lot of cases to handle: out of disk-space, hardlinks, softlinks, file permissions, file ownership, etc.

I've tried to find existing backup programs that can do this but I have not found any.

So my question is: How do I most easily do this? Writing it from scratch would probably take too much time. So I was wondering if I could put it on top of something existing. Any ideas?

Comment: This is a very good question, but I'm afraid you've posted it on the wrong side.  If others agree to close it here, don't worry, it belongs on Super User instead, because it's not a programming question.

Comment: Well, I see you point. It is only a programing question if I have to program it - then the question is which libraries or what else to use to implement it as quick as possible. If I don't have to program it is not belonging here.

Comment: Make `rsync`  run periodically thru `cron`

Comment: rsync will not do. The disks are offline, when not doing the backup

Answer (score 0):

If I were in your shoes I would [buy an external hard drive](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007601+600361775&QksAutoSuggestion=&ShowDeactivatedMark=False&Configurator=&IsNodeId=1&Subcategory=414&description=&hisInDesc=&Ntk=&CFG=&SpeTabStoreType=&AdvancedSearch=1&srchInDesc=) that is large enough to hold all your data.

Then write a Bash script that would:

1. Mount the external hard drive
2. Execute `rsync` to back up everything that has changed
3. Unmount the external hard drive
4. Send me a message (e-mail or whatever) letting me know the backup is complete

So you'd plug in your external drive, execute the Bash script and then return the external hard drive to a safe deposit box at a bank (or other similarly secure location).

Comment: I would need 2 disks as one always has to be out of the house. It is of course an option, but the other way I wouldn't have to buy hardware I really don't need. It is what I have done so far - not with rsync and email though. And as my data increases in size, I end up having a lot of external drives that are too small for my backup.

Comment: @AndersBoRasmussen The only thing I can think of if you insist on using multiple disks would be to come up with some kind of scheme involving LVM and rsync.